# Extracting multiple elements within nested structure of array spark dataframe 2.4

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, aws-glue

I am reading a parquet file and trying to extract elements within a Struct of Struct of Array. The null values however are returning empty when I use getItem(). This pattern works in Spark 1.6 but now using Spark 2.4 in aws glue it seems to ignore the null values and only pulls empty.

Input is parquet but I have written in JSON format:

```
{
   "ExampleMessage":{
      "activity":{
         "exampleSport":[
            {
               "exampleRole":null
            },
            {
               "exampleRole":null
            },
            {
               "exampleRole":"Runner"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Attempted Extraction:

```
raw_df.select(col("ExampleMessage.activity").getItem("exampleSport").getItem("exampleRole"))
```

Current Output:

```
,,Runner
```

Desired Output:

```
null,null,Runner
```

Comment: What code do you call to obtain your output ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code instead of `null` you will get `None`

```
raw_df.select(col("ExampleMessage.activity").getItem("exampleSport").getItem("exampleRole")).head()
```

output will be

```
 Row(ExampleMessage.activity AS `activity`.exampleSport.exampleRole=[None, None, 'Runner'])
```